# Elasticsearch and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

Trying to learn Elasticsearch and AngularJS by making a simple search app.

I know best practice with Angular is to modularize all the code but...

I went through a tutorial and have some sample code and it looks good, its just not broken down into modules, it looks like this:

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', ['elasticsearch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

searchApp.controller('typeahead', ['ui.bootstrap', function(ui.bootstrap){
  //add $http get
}]);//added

searchApp.controller('SearchResultsList', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'filterService', '$sce', function($scope, searchService, filterService, $sce) {
```

and a whole lot of code after that.

Is it worth it to try and break it down into modules (controllers, services, filters and app.js with config and routes?

Any advice, recommendations are highly appreciated.

Comment: it depends how complicated it gets :). Once you start getting confused in a controller I'd start thinking about refactoring into services

Comment: You should also check out [Elastic UI](http://www.elasticui.com/).

Comment: @user2954587 thanks for suggestion - I think Im going to follow it. Some pain today for a better tomorrow.

Comment: @Val thanks for the link, looks like a very promising project, do you know if elastic.js is at all similar to the official js client from Elastic?

Comment: The goal of elastic.js is to provide support for building the query DSL that you're going to be sending via the official JS client. Not sure how current that library is since it's not been updated recently on Github even though things are moving on the ES query DSL front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the AngularJs best practices and documentation, controllers should not have your business logic. I think its better to modularized your application.

As u know:

#### Use controllers to:

- Set up the initial state of the $scope object.
- Add behavior to the $scope object.

#### Do not use controllers to:

- Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.
- Format input — Use angular form controls instead.
- Filter output — Use angular filters instead.
- Share code or state across controllers — Use angular services instead.
- Manage the life-cycle of other component

Comment: As related to the comments above, going to modularize, thanks for the advice!